# What is the recommended way to update multiple TextView with a 1000ms pause in between

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, sleep

I have an activity, in it there's a public void that executes a lot of code and updates some textviews with some information about the process as it goes. I want to be able to pause the code for about a second every time a textview is updated (and have the update show up on the GUI). The desired result is a smooth series of changes rather than everything happening all at once.

I read that one way to do this is to use a handler with a delay but is that the best way when I have to do it several times (requiring a lot of stacking them together)?

I also have a separate async task running, and I want it to continue running even while the rest of the code is paused.

What is the best way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: you heard well  a Handler is your friend

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate all your data in your code as it is now but don't update any UI elements (like a `TextView`) then create a new `Thread` and make it update one `TextView`, then delay it for 1000ms (1 sec).

```
{
    //Your calculations take place here
    //...

    //Make your class extend Runnable, or create a new Runnable class - I hope you are familiar with threads
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

run()
{
    //Update UI - when updating UI from outside main thread use the view.post(Runnable) method instead of directly changing it's text
    textView.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                textView.setText(yourText);
            } 
        }

    //Make thread sleep for 1000ms (or 1sec)
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}

    //Here you can update more UI elements and after each one make Thread delay again for 1 second
    //...
}
```

I haven't worked with handlers yet so I can't say if it's better or not, but I know it works